# How to use multiple res.render() in one Express app.get()

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to use res.render multiple times in the same app.get(). Each res.render() should render details from a seperate database table.

I have tried using Express middleware with next() but I can't get to work.

Can someone explain how I can render multiple elements? Thanks!

```js
app.get("/add-item", getCategories, getPayees);

function getCategories(req, res) {
   // Code here
   Category.find({}, function (err, categories) {
     res.render("add-item", {
       savedCategories: categories
    });
  });
};

function getPayees(req, res) {
   // Code here
   Payee.find({}, function (err, payees) {
     res.render("add-item", {
       savedPayees: payees
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<form action="/add-item" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="itemCategory">Category</label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="itemCategory" name="itemCategory">

        <% savedCategories.forEach(function(category) { %>
          <option><%= category.name %></option>
        <% }); %>

      </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="itemPayee">Payee</label>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="itemPayee" name="itemPayee">

        <% savedPayees.forEach(function(payee) { %>
          <option><%= payee.name %></option>
        <% }); %>

      </select>

    </div>

    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to call res.render multiples times. Instead, add your data to res.locals and then render the page:

```
app.get("/add-item", getCategories, getPayees, renderForm);

function getCategories(req, res, next) {
   // Code here
   Category.find({}, function (err, categories) {
     if (err) next(err);
     res.locals.savedCategories = categories;
     next();
   });
};

function getPayees(req, res, next) {
   // Code here
   Payee.find({}, function (err, payees) {
     if (err) next(err);
     res.locals.savedPayees = payees;
     next();
   });
};

function renderForm(req, res) {
    res.render("add-item");
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I needed :)